# Can I send an event through my webhook directly to an Azure Event Hub?

Tags: azure-functions, twilio, webhooks, azure-eventhub

Is it possible to send a message to an Azure Event Hub using a Webhook from an SMS API such as Twilio or CM Telecom directly to an Azure Event Hub? If so, how do I proceed with authentication such as SAS? Do I have to use an Azure function?
I've read about "event subscriptions" and thought it might be useful for this integration, but I'm not sure how it's being used yet and if it's useful for this use case.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this is not possible, the best way to do this is to send the webhook to an azure HTTP trigger function which then sends the data of the event to the event hub, another main reason to do this is also that the event hub returns a 201 response while most API's expect a 200 response, so you will still need an azure function between the webhook and event hub.